# How to search for multiple registers in a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, search, struct

I have choice 2 that I need to fix. For example, if I have a name Marcus and user types in 'arc' should show all the names that contain 'arc' not just Marcus. My code works if I only type the whole name and only shows one line(register) anyways. 
And then I have choice 3 lagersaldo ( stands for quantity ). If user registered 3 things for example with quantity.. 20, when search all the items with quantity 20 should show up. The code only shows one of them. Anyone can help solve this?

```
struct varor{
        int varunummer;
        char namn[WORDLENGTH];
        int lagersaldo;
    };
            if(choice=='2'){
                int i, namn;
                printf("Ange namn: ");
                scanf("%d", &namn);
                i = ifNamnExists(namn, reg, nrOfGoods);
                if(i>0){
                    printf("\nVarunummer \t Namn \t\t\t Lagersaldo\n");
                    printf(" %d \t\t %s \t\t\t %d\n",reg[i].varunummer,reg[i].namn,reg[i].lagersaldo);
                }else printf("\nNamn finns inte!\n");
            }
            if(choice=='3'){
                int i, lagersaldo;
                printf("Ange lagersaldo: ");
                scanf("%d", &lagersaldo);
                i = ifLagersaldoExist(lagersaldo, reg, nrOfGoods);
                if(i>0){
                    printf("\nVarunummer \t Namn \t\t\t Lagersaldo\n");
                    printf(" %d \t\t %s \t\t\t %d\n",reg[i].varunummer,reg[i].namn,reg[i].lagersaldo);
                }else printf("\nLagersaldo för det nr. finns inte!\n");
            }
            if(choice=='4') run=0;
}

int ifNamnExists(char namn, const struct varor reg[], int nrOfGoods){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < nrOfGoods; i++){
        if(strcmp(&namn, reg[i].namn)==0){
            return i;
        }
    }
  return -1;
}
int ifVarunummerExist(int varunummer, const struct varor reg[], int nrOfGoods){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<nrOfGoods; i++)
        if(reg[i].varunummer == varunummer)
            return i;
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Show us the functions : ifNamnExists() and ifLagersaldoExist() and show us the structure. If possible show us the full code.

Comment: @MukulKumar updated now. The whole code is 300 lines long I hope this is enough

Comment: `int i, namn;` --> `int i; char namn[WORDLENGTH];`, `scanf("%d", &namn);` --> `scanf("%s", namn);`, `if(i>0){` --> `if(i>=0){`, `int ifNamnExists(char namn,` --> `int ifNamnExists(char namn[],`

Comment: For partial name match, use `strstr` instead of `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

As @BLUEPIXY has pointed out in short, your code needs a few modifications.

- You are treating a **substring** as an **integer** rather than a **string**.
- You are using `strcmp()` to check if a string has a **substring** while **strcmp()** does not work like that, it checks for the equality of two strings and returns a `0` value so, check out this function `strstr()`.
- You are returning the value in your for loop inside `ifNamnExists()`. A return statement returns the control back to the place where it was called. So, as soon as your code finds something, it returns back without iterating any further, same goes with the other function `ifVarunummerExist()`.